# How to make Network Bonding in 16.04.1?

Tags: network-bonding

I want to make Network Bonding in 16.04.1, i know need ifenslave to complete it.
The ifenslave base on network manager for this function.
But what setting need modify in network manager? How modify setting in ifenslave to content Network Bonding?
If don't use ifenslave make Network Bonding, does any solution for Network Bonding?

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/699681/231142