# NIC Teaming under Ubuntu 16.04 - Can only ping DNS servers and nothing else

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dns

I have a bond setup currently in active-backup configuration. What I am trying to do is setup these two NICs in a configuration that will utilize the majority of bandwidth that both NICs can provide.

Would this be mode 3 (broadcast)?

My current configuration is as such:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#eth0:0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Bonding eth0 & eth1 to create bond0 NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
gateway 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

When I check the status I do see:

```
mlavender@~$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: eth0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: eth0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 9c:5c:8e:4f:1b:87
Slave queue ID: 0
```

How would I configure this so that both NICs are being utlized at the same time so I can effectively transmit more than 1GB?

**Additional information**

I have a Netgear GS724T ProSafe switch. I have two ports configured in a LAG and it is enabled. It does support – IEEE 802.3ad static and/or dynamic link aggregation

From what I can tell, I can ping the hosts defined as DNS servers.  Local gateway and both Google DNS servers. I cannot ping anything else. Also of course running apt-get update fails because name resolution issues.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Tried running tracepath

```
tracepath 8.8.8.8

mlavender@~$ tracepath 8.8.8.8
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.254                                         0.831ms
 1:  192.168.1.254                                         0.914ms
 2:  xxx.xxx.x.xxx                                       168.148ms
 3:  71.149.77.116                                         5.205ms
 4:  75.8.128.144                                          4.537ms
 5:  12.83.68.145                                          6.995ms
 6:  12.122.85.197                                        10.035ms asymm  7
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
```

I can ping Google DNS servers. I can ping anything on the LAN. Updated interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-master eth0

# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Bonding eth0 & eth1 to create bond0 NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
bond-mode 802.3ad
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

I did also go into the switch and rather than having the LAG type set to static, I switched it to LACP.

Comment: You might need the `network` and  `broadcast` lines added to your `bond0` settings.  I am not 100% sure on that one if it is needed, but I have configured bonding many times at my job.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/699681/231142) is a little outdated as it was for Ubuntu 14.04, but it should still work.  I will check my notes when I am at work for 16.04 bonding but I don't expect it to be much different.

Comment: Thanks  I will look at it. I appreciate your help on this!

Comment: You can also try **mode 4** *802.3ad* on your `bond0` as that is for Link Aggregation, but if I remember right your switch might also need to support that, which it looks like it does.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding#Descriptions_of_bonding_modes

Comment: This is what I have right now:  

https://pastebin.com/raw/Tc2qdGpv

Comment: It should be `bond-primary eth0`.  You accidentally have two `bond-master` lines in the `auto eth0` section.

Comment: I think I got it!

https://pastebin.com/raw/Ji8BQRJd I had to reboot coimpletely but after Ubuntu came back up, I now have the config you see in the pastebin link.  I think this is in fact working :)  I still cant get outside the LAN though.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60616/discussion-between-martin-and-terrance).

Comment: I cannot chat, but it also sounds like you may not have any `resolv.conf` nameservers configured.  Look at the answers on this one:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/143819/how-do-i-configure-my-static-dns-in-interfaces

Comment: That did it!  Had to reboot again but it came back up, I can actually ping by hostname, and I was able to run apt-get update. Thanks  If you want to post that as the answer I will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the fix for this was to edit my resolv.conf file. Once I did this, I rebooted the server, and voila! Magic!

Thanks for all the help on this. For anyone who needs it, this will get you two NICs bonded together in a working LAG. Make sure your switch it setup for LACP also.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Bonding eth0 & eth1 to create bond0 NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 10.0.0.90
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.250
dns-nameserver 10.0.0.250 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves all
```